# how to update an subscription without id in mail chimp rest api

Tags: rest, email, mailchimp

I really like the new Mail Chimp REST API - it is easy to create subscriptions by PUT and those can be updated using the subscription id.

But I would like to update a subscription simply using the email address, because I do not want to save any new Mail Chimp Id in my Middle-ware application, as long as the email should be sufficient as identifier?

To update a List Member the API is:

```
/lists/{list_id}/members/{id}
```

but I would prefer a simpler way:

```
/lists/{list_id}/members/{email}
```

is something like this possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The subscriber's ID is the MD5 hash of their email address. Since you would have to make a function call to URL Encode the email address for your second way, using the first way is just as easy.

See this [help document on managing subscribers](http://kb.mailchimp.com/api/article/how-to-manage-subscribers) for more details.

Answer (score 0):

More specifics on updating a subscriber via MailChimp's REST API.

```js
// node/javascript specific, but pretty basic PUT request to MailChimp API endpoint

// dependencies (npm)
var request = require('request'),
    url = require('url'),
    crypto = require('crypto');

// variables
var datacenter = "yourMailChimpDatacenter", // something like 'us11' (after '-' in api key)
    listId = "yourMailChimpListId",
    email = "subscriberEmailAddress",
    apiKey = "yourMailChimpApiKey";

// mailchimp options
var options = {
    url: url.parse('https://'+datacenter+'.api.mailchimp.com/3.0/lists/'+listId+'/members/'+crypto.createHash('md5').update(email).digest('hex')),
    headers: {
        'Authorization': 'authId '+apiKey // any string works for auth id
    },
    json: true,
    body: {
        email_address: email,
        status_if_new: 'pending', // pending if new subscriber -> sends 'confirm your subscription' email
        status: 'subscribed',            
        merge_fields: {
            FNAME: "subscriberFirstName",
            LNAME: "subscriberLastName"
        },
        interests: {
            MailChimpListGroupId: true // if you're using groups within your list
        }
    }
};

// perform update
request.put(options, function(err, response, body) {
    if (err) {
        // handle error
    } else {
        console.log('subscriber added to mailchimp list');
    }
});
```